# como acomodar AJAX JSON para haga filtrado de busqueda?

Tags: php, ajax, json

lo que pasa es que agarre una pagina ya de internet, y quiero que haga en el cuadro una busqueda, una busqueda especifica dentro de lo que ya esta filtrado.

```
      //Filtracion
$sWhere = "WHERE nomTipo ='Administrador'";//filtra los que solo son administradores
```

ese es la linea donde hace el filtrado de puros administradores,

lo que pasa es que cuando hago la busqueda con el cuadro quita el filtrado que ya tenia y busca toda en la tabla, quiero poner esa restriccion,

estes el codigo completo

```html
<?php
 /*
  * Script:    Tablas de multiples datos del lado del servidor para PHP y MySQL
  * Copyright: 2016 - Marko Robles
  * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
 */
 
 require '../php_conexion.php';
 
 /* Nombre de La Tabla */
 $sTabla = "usuarios";

 /* Array que contiene los nombres de las columnas de la tabla*/
 $aColumnas = array( 'nomTipo','idUsuario','nomUsuario', 'nickUsuario', 'ultFechaActivo','emailUsuario','telUsuario','nomDistrOrigen','estadoDistr','estado');
 
 /* columna indexada */
 $sIndexColumn = "nomTipo";
 
 // Paginacion
 $sLimit = "";
 if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
 {
  $sLimit = "LIMIT ".$_GET['iDisplayStart'].", ".$_GET['iDisplayLength'];
 }
 
 
 //Ordenacion
 if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
 {
  $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
  {
   if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
   {
    $sOrder .= $aColumnas[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
    ".$_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] .", ";
   }
  }
  
  $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
  if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
  {
   $sOrder = "";
  }
 }
 
 //Filtracion
 $sWhere = "WHERE nomTipo ='Administrador'";//filtra los que solo son administradores
 if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
 {
  $sWhere = "WHERE (";
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
  {
   $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
  }
  $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
  $sWhere .= ')';
 }
 
 // Filtrado de columna individual 
 for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
 {
  if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
  {
   if ( $sWhere == "" )
   {
    $sWhere = "WHERE ";
   }
   else
   {
    $sWhere .= " AND ";
   }
   $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%' ";
  }
 }
 
 
 //Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
 FROM   $sTabla
 $sWhere
 $sOrder
 $sLimit
 ";
 $rResult = $conexion->query($sQuery);
 
 /* Data set length after filtering */
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
 ";
 $rResultFilterTotal = $conexion->query($sQuery);
 $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
 $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
 
 /* Total data set length */
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
 FROM   $sTabla
 ";
 $rResultTotal = $conexion->query($sQuery);
 $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
 $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
 
 /*
  * Output
 */
 $output = array(
 "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
 "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
 "aaData" => array()
 );
 
 while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_array())
 {
 // if( $aRow['nomTipo']=='Distribuidor'){
  $row = array();
  
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
  {
   
   if ( $aColumnas[$i] == "version" )
   {    
    /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
    $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
   }
   else if ( $aColumnas[$i] != ' ')
   {
    /* General output */
    if( $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]==$aRow['ultFechaActivo']){
     $row[]=strftime( "%d de %B de %Y",strtotime( $aRow['ultFechaActivo']));
    }else if($aRow[$aColumnas[$i]]==$aRow['idUsuario']){
       
      }else {
       $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i]];
      }
   }
  }
  
  $row[] = "<td><a href='detalles_usuario.php?ID=".$aRow['idUsuario']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a></td>";
  
  
     
  #$row[]= "<td><img src=".$aRow['imag1']." width=70 heigth=70 ></td>";
  
  $output['aaData'][] = $row;
 //}
 }
 echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

esta es mi tabla ya filtrada, como en el codigo
[image: primera pantalla]

ahi ya esta filtrada que tengo en el codigo, por TIPO-ADMINISTRADOR pero si en el cuadro buscar le pongo cualquier cosa, "a" por ejemplo me busca todas las cosas que tenga "a" de toda mi tabla y quita el filtrado que ya tenia de ADMINISTRADORES
ASI

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo algo tiene que ser en la parte donde diga FILTRACION  de mi codigo, mas no se donde y como hacer ese cambio para que busque tan solo en lo que ya he filtrado

Comment: No se entiende que es lo que intentas xonseguir

Comment: gracias, ya agregue mas informacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bueno es que si tedas de cuenta en esta parte:

```
//Filtracion
    $sWhere = "WHERE nomTipo ='Administrador'";//filtra los que solo son administradores
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
```

reescribes la variable `$sWhere="WHERE nomTipo ='Administrador'";` por `$sWhere = "WHERE (";` entonces coloca algo como:

```
//Filtracion
    $sWhere = "WHERE nomTipo ='Administrador'";//filtra los que solo son administradores
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere .= " AND (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
```

Comment: Gracias junior si funciono, solo que el código lo deje así

Comment: //Filtracion
    $sWhere = "WHERE nomTipo ='Administrador'";//filtra los que solo son administradores
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere .= "WHERE nomTipo='Administrador'  AND (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

Comment: quitale el punto de concatenacion en ese caso